# Stripe 3D secure and regular payment setup

Tags: javascript, php, html, stripe-payments, 3d-secure

I have a Stripe 3D secure payment setup, I have been using it for multiple sites before. However when usually using it, I have limited it to only 3D secured cards and nothing else. Now I would like to be able to also accept a credit card on which 3D secure isn't supported. In my current setup of which I have fully attached in code below, I am creating a 3D secure source and submitting the finished source to my chargeCard.php file to charge the card.

I am creating the 3D Secure source within the main.js and api.js files. Within the api.js file, is where it checks whether the card supports 3D Secure or not. Specifically on lines 24 to 28 is where it would check, incase the card is not supporting the 3D secure setup. This is where I have made an attempt at just submitting the card source directly to the form and then submit it for a charge, like a regular charge without the 3D secure. However nothing happens and it just keeps saying "Loading... Please wait..." which it is set to say in the main.js until something is happening, meaning nothing is happening in this case.

My question is, how would I change it up, so the whole 3D secure system works. But incase the card submitted doesn't support 3D secure, and is still chargeable, then it would just make a regular charge without 3D secure?

Note when running the script using a card supporting 3D secure it works perfectly. Everything is running as supposed and charge is made, it is just not working at all, when using a card not supporting 3D Secure.

Underneath is attached HTML form, main.js, api.js and chargeCard.php

### HTML Form

```
<form action="chargeCard.php" method="POST" id="payment-form" name="payment-form">

                    <input type="text" name="firstName" id="fName" placeholder="Firstname"><br>
                    <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lName" placeholder="Lastname"><br>
                    <input type="text" name="country" id="countryFr" placeholder="Country"><br>
                    <input type="text" name="emailPer" id="emailPer" placeholder="Email"><br>

                    <input type="text" name="cardNum" id="cardNumId" placeholder="Card number"><br>

                    <select name="expMonth"  id="expMonthId"  class="card-expiry-month">
                    <option value="">Exp: Month</option>
                    <option value="1">01</option>
                    <option value="2">02</option>
                    <option value="3">03</option>
                    <option value="4">04</option>
                    <option value="5">05</option>
                    <option value="6">06</option>
                    <option value="7">07</option>
                    <option value="8">08</option>
                    <option value="9">09</option>
                    <option value="10">10</option>
                    <option value="11">11</option>
                    <option value="12">12</option>
                </select>

                <select name="expYear"  id="expYearId" class="card-expiry-year">
                    <option value="">Exp: Year</option>
                    <option value="2019">2019</option>
                    <option value="2020">2020</option>
                    <option value="2021">2021</option>
                    <option value="2022">2022</option>
                    <option value="2023">2023</option>
                    <option value="2024">2024</option>
                    <option value="2025">2025</option>
                    <option value="2026">2026</option>
                    <option value="2027">2027</option>
                    <option value="2028">2028</option>
                    <option value="2029">2029</option>
                    <option value="2030">2030</option>
                    <option value="2031">2031</option>
                    <option value="2032">2032</option>
                    <option value="2033">2033</option>
                    <option value="2034">2034</option>
                    <option value="2035">2035</option>
                    <option value="2036">2036</option>
                    <option value="2037">2037</option>
                    <option value="2038">2038</option>
                    <option value="2039">2039</option>
                     <option value="2040">2040</option>
                </select>
                    <br>
                    <input type="text" name="cvcCard" id="cvcID" placeholder="CVC"><br>

                    <br>

                    <input type="button" id="customButton" value="Finish" form="chargeForm" onClick="startAuthFunc();">


                    </form>

<div class="row">

          <div class="col-lg-3">
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-6" id="iframe-payment">
          </div><!-- iframe for the 3D secure checking-->
          <div class="col-lg-3">
          </div>

          </div>

          </div>
```

### main.js

```
function startAuthFunc() {
  const paymentRequest = {
    cardNumber: document.getElementById('cardNumId').value, 
    expYear: document.getElementById('expYearId').value, 
    expMonth: document.getElementById('expMonthId').value, 
    cvc: document.getElementById('cvcID').value, 
    currency: 'USD', 
    amount: 1000, 
    nativeElement: document.querySelector('#iframe-payment')
  };


  paymentRequest.nativeElement.innerHTML = 'Loading... Please wait...';

  doPayment(paymentRequest).then((result) => {
    console.log('result --> ', result);
    paymentRequest.nativeElement.innerHTML = 'Success! Your details are correct!';
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    paymentRequest.nativeElement.innerHTML = 'We are unable to validate your details...';
    alert('Something went wrong, sorry!' + error);
  });

}
```

### api.js

```
function doPayment(paymentRequest) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const onCreateCardCallback = create3DSecure(paymentRequest, resolve, reject);
    return Stripe.source.create({
      type: 'card',
      card: {
        number: paymentRequest.cardNumber,
        cvc: paymentRequest.cvc,
        exp_month: paymentRequest.expMonth,
        exp_year: paymentRequest.expYear
      }
    }, onCreateCardCallback);
  });
}

function create3DSecure(paymentRequest, resolve, reject) {
  return (status, cardResponse) => {
    console.log('create3DSecure --> paymentRequest', paymentRequest);
    console.log('create3DSecure --> status', status);
    console.log('create3DSecure --> createSourceResponse', cardResponse);

    if (status !== 200 || cardResponse.error) {  // problem  //Check if the 3D secure card status
      reject(cardResponse.error);
    }else if (cardResponse.card.three_d_secure === 'not_supported' && cardResponse.status === 'chargeable') {
  //my attempt...
  var $form = $('#payment-form');
  $form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="stripeSource" />').val(source.id));
  $form.get(0).submit();

    } else if(cardResponse.card.three_d_secure === 'optional' || cardResponse.card.three_d_secure === 'required') {
      const onCreate3DSecureCallback = createIframe(paymentRequest, resolve, reject);

      Stripe.source.create({ //Create the 3D Secure source for 3D secure check and charge
        type: 'three_d_secure',
        amount: paymentRequest.amount, //Amount of payment 
        currency: paymentRequest.currency, //The currency of which the payment is done in
        three_d_secure: { card: cardResponse.id }, //Source ID 
        redirect: { return_url: window.location.href } //Redirect to the location the checking started
      }, onCreate3DSecureCallback);
    }
    else {
      reject(cardResponse);
    }
  };
}

function createIframe(paymentRequest, resolve, reject) {
  return (status, stripe3dsResponse) => {
    console.log('Create the Iframe --> paymentRequest', paymentRequest);
    console.log('Create the Iframe --> status', status);
    console.log('Create the Iframe --> stripe3dsResponse', stripe3dsResponse);

    if (status !== 200 || stripe3dsResponse.error) {  // problem
      reject(stripe3dsResponse.error);
    } else {
      paymentRequest.nativeElement.innerHTML =
        '<iframe style="width:100%; height: 320px;" frameborder="0" src="' + stripe3dsResponse.redirect.url + '"></iframe>';

      const onPollCallbackReal = onPollCallback(paymentRequest, resolve, reject);
      Stripe.source.poll(stripe3dsResponse.id, stripe3dsResponse.client_secret, onPollCallbackReal);
    }
  };
}

function onPollCallback(paymentRequest, resolve, reject) {
  return (status, source) => {
    console.log('onPoolCallback --> ', source);

    if (status !== 200 || source.error) {
      console.log('onPoolCallback --> REJECT --> not 200 or error --> ', source);
      reject(source.error);
    } else if (source.status === 'canceled' || source.status === 'consumed' || source.status === 'failed') {
      console.log('onPoolCallback --> REJECT --> canceled/consumed/fail --> ', source);
      reject(source.status);
    } else if (/* source.three_d_secure.authenticated && */ source.status === 'chargeable') {
      /* some cards do not need to be authenticated, like the 4242 4242 4242 4242 */
      // get the payment form
      var $form = $('#payment-form');
      console.log('onPoolCallback --> SUCCESS --> ', source);
      resolve(source);
      $form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="stripeSource" />').val(source.id));
      $form.get(0).submit();
    }
  };
}
```

### chargeCard.php

```
<?php

require_once('./stripe-php-4.4.0/init.php');

// Set your secret key: find on https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_12345678910");

// Get the payment source submitted by the form:
$sourceGet = $_POST['stripeSource'];
$paymentAmount = 1000;

try {

        $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
        "amount" => $paymentAmount,
        "currency" => "usd",
        "source" => $sourceGet,
        ));

        if (charge.succeeded) {



        } else if (charge.failed) {
            $message = "Something went wrong and the payment failed";
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
        }

} catch(\Stripe\Error\Card $e) {
        $message2 = "The card was declined, when trying to make payment";
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message2');</script>";
}

?>
```